# R foreach with .combine=rbindlist

Tags: r, data.table

I am using foreach with a .combine = rbindlist. This does not appear to work, although it works fine if I use .combine = rbind.

Just to illustrate using a simple example --

```
> t2 <- data.table(col1=c(1,2,3))
> foreach (i=1:3, .combine=rbind) %dopar% unique(t2)
   col1
1:    1
2:    2
3:    3
4:    1
5:    2
6:    3
7:    1
8:    2
9:    3

# But using rbindlist gives an error

> foreach (i=1:3, .combine=rbindlist) %dopar% unique(t2)
error calling combine function:
<simpleError in fun(result.1, result.2): unused argument(s) (result.2)>
NULL
```

Has anyone been able to make this work ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I understand that we should be calling rbindlist on a list object - rbindlist(list(dt1, dt2)) ... but not sure how to perform it using the foreach .combine function.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's basically what you said - `rbindlist` assumes a `list` argument, and the error you're getting is the same as this one:

```
result.1 = data.table(blah = 23)
result.2 = data.table(blah = 34)

rbindlist(result.1, result.2)
#Error in rbindlist(result.1, result.2) : unused argument (result.2)
```

If you want to utilize `rbindlist`, the way to do it would be this:

```
rbindlist(foreach (i = 1:3) %dopar% unique(t2))
```

or this:

```
foreach (i=1:3, .combine=function(x,y)rbindlist(list(x,y))) %dopar% unique(t2)
```

Comment: Your first solution using `.combine=list` fails when there are more than 100 results since you get a nested list in that case.  Just leave out the `.combine` and `.multicombine` arguments and it works fine since the default behavior is to return the results in a list.  I like your second solution best, and it works with any number of results.

Comment: @SteveWeston see the .maxcombine comment and ?foreach

Comment: Do you mean you expected your example to only work if you set `.maxcombine` to be greater than the number of tasks?  That's pretty fragile, especially since you can't always tell how many tasks there are.  Neither of the other examples depend on `.maxcombine` for correctness.  It's supposed to be a tuning parameter.

Comment: @SteveWeston `Inf` is always greater than the number of tasks (I haven't checked if `foreach` will eat that value, but I don't see why it shoudln't, I'll check a bit later)

Comment: Using `.maxcombine=Inf` doesn't work since that value is used for allocating the buffer to process the results.  But even if it did work, I don't see why you'd ever want to use `list` as a combine function when the default behavior is to return the results in a list, and will work correctly regardless of the value of `.maxcombine`.

Answer (score 14):

Here's a way to both use rbindlist as your `.combine` function *and have `.multicombine=TRUE`*:

```
foreach (i=1:3,
         .combine=function(...) rbindlist(list(...)),
         .multicombine=TRUE) %dopar% unique(t2)
```

If you have a decent amount of seperate results to aggregate, this could be quite a bit faster than only combining two-at-a-time.

For a single foreach statement, this produces the same result as letting `foreach` default `.combine` to list and wrapping with rbindlist, as in eddi's first solution. I'm not sure which is faster, though I would expect them to be close.

For small, single-`foreach` jobs I like wrapping with `rbindlist`, but when chaining several `foreach`'s together with `%:%` I think the above approach (likely in the first `foreach`) looks cleaner.

Comment: This kind of combine function works well with a parallel backend that calls the combine function on-the-fly.  That allows the master to perform post-processing in parallel with the workers.  It's even more useful when the combine function performs a reduction.

Comment: You can also use `rbindlist` directly as a ".final" function with the default combine function since that produces a list.  That's a very clean solution, but I would use your combine function.

Comment: Ah I didn't know about `.final`! I've got a few places that will look cleaner. 
As for your first comment, that's exactly how I've been using, with the `doMPI` package. It's really nice not waiting for all the children to finish before the parent does anything when you have thousands of individual jobs.

Comment: ClaytonJY and Steve Weston would either of you have an example of how you set up the master to perform post-processing in parallel with the workers?

Comment: @CooperBuckeye05 I haven't used this pattern in some time (today I'd use the `future` or `furrr` packages), but I don't recall doing any special configuration beyond using a compliant backend. `doMPI` was one of the few backends that did this, so I'd recommend following installation & configuration instruction for that package. biggest drawback I recall was it didn't work on Windows.

Comment: @ClaytonJY  Thanks for the reply.  Yeah I have a windows machine where I am brute forcing a round 2 million + calculations.  It takes roughly 4 hours to compute, and another 2 to 3 hours to assemble the list/dataframe (and repeat another 15 to 20 times) , so I am looking for any speedup advantage possible.  Does future/furrr offer this performance advantage with the master doing some of the table/list assembly from the slaves?  Will foreach work with furrr, or will I need to rebuild my code/function?  Thanks for answering my questions!!

Comment: @CooperBuckeye05 Unfortunately I have no idea which backends or interfaces support parallel combination currently. If those 2 million+ calculations are each individual jobs, the overhead of dispatching those jobs may far outweigh the gains of parallelization. You might try batching your work so one job does many computations and combines them appropriately to reduce communication overhead. You may be able to use doMPI on a virtual machine w/ linux or WSL2; I'm not too sure. Good luck!