# Is it a good idea to read/write files in parallel?

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing

I have a large number of data files that describe the weather at a large number of weather stations. These files are hourly, and are contained in files separated by date.

For example:

```
20100101.csv
20100102.csv
20100103.csv
.
.
20140228.csv
```

I need to aggregate the data by *station* and then write it to disk. That is, for each of those weather files, I need to extract the data for station **i** and then write it to disk.

The output:

```
station_001.csv
station_002.csv
.
.
station_999.csv
```

To speed things up, I decided to read in the daily files in parallel using the `foreach` and `doMC` packages, and I also write the station files to disk after aggregating by stations in parallel.

More specifically, I used `foreach` to read in the files and combined them using `.combine="rbind"` (I have enough memory to make one huge data set in memory). Afterwards, I have another `foreach` loop where I subset the data by station and then write to disk. I found that I experienced a very good speed boost by doing the read/write in parallel.

My question is: Is it a good idea to read/write in parallel? I made sure that different threads do not read the same data file or write to the same station file, but after some googling, it seems that it may not be a good idea to parallelize i/o tasks? ([Example I found saying no to parallel Input/Output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1993699/how-to-parallelize-file-reading-and-writing), and a [post on R-bloggers showing parallel reads](http://www.r-bloggers.com/import-all-text-files-in-a-folder-with-parallel-execution/))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Performance Pro

- Using multiple threads can increase performance on a multi-core machine

Performance Con

- When reading from disk, CPU performance is typically not your bottleneck. Files on disk are, more often than not, written in as many sequential blocks as possible. This means that the pointer on your spinning disk does not have to move as far to read the next segment. If you perform the task in parallel, the pointer has to move repeatedly to pick up wherever it left off. This means that your disk write speed will ultimately be slower*.

  *Solid-state drives may not have this problem (I don't know much about SSD's, but I imagine they aren't impacted at all by context switching).

Comment: Some SSD's are not impacted at all but typically they're using internal parallelism in order to deliver data at optimal speed anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I suspected something similar to what you mentioned as a performance con. I wonder if each of the threads that are created compete for writing to disk, or if the tasks are buffered. I do not have SSDs on the machine that I am working on.

Comment: @ialm I guarantee that if two threads are writing a large file to disk at the same time, they will compete. If you have ever downloaded two large files from the Internet at the same time, then you know that this occurs, because you can see the progress bar of each file moving.

Comment: @John OK, that makes sense. I will try benchmarking with and without parallel writes. Is this the same for *reading* files in parallel?

Comment: @ialm If two independent threads are reading two different files in parallel, your disk will exhibit a "read-seek-read" pattern.  A disk's read speed is typically *much* faster than its seek speed, so if you do a lot of seeking, it will surely slow down. I predict that your benchmark will not only show that parallel is slower than sequential, but that parallel will be *more than twice as slow*.

Comment: @John OK, one more comment - I learned from the CS's that the development system that I am working on is using a RAID5 setup, so they are saying that the performance increase that I am seeing in parallel reads is because of this set-up. I guess this is due to multiple disks having the same files being available for reading. They also agree that writing in parallel is probably a bad idea.

Comment: Yes, that will make multiple reads faster, but only a few depending on the setup. If you are doing too many in parallel you'll start to see slowdowns again.

Comment: Thank you, John and John! I did not notice that there were two of you. I was wondering why the top level comment was from the same person... cheers!

Answer (score 3):

You say you notice performance improvements, so then it's obviously a good idea for you.

Additional ways to speed things up - check out `fread` in `data.table` - that will speed up sequential reading significantly (by a factor of 3 or more). Using `rbindlist` (also from `data.table`) to combine should also provide speed ups (example usage with `foreach` here - [R foreach with .combine=rbindlist](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17411223/817778)).

Comment: I noticed performance improvements, but I was worried about other things, such as data corruption, etc. Maybe I'm being paranoid. Thanks for the suggestions with `fread` and `rbindlist` - I will definitely look at `data.table` in the future.