# Time estimation of parallel process of nested loops

Tags: r, loops, foreach, parallel-processing, doparallel

I have the following code:

```
library(foreach)
  library(doParallel)
  N<-5
  cl<-makeCluster(4)
  registerDoParallel(cl)

  start.time <- Sys.time()

  #loop
  #result is a list of vectors
  s8 <- foreach(i=1:N) %:%
    foreach(j=i:N, .combine='c') %dopar% {

      as.numeric (i+j)    } ## In reality there is something more complicated

  stopCluster(cl) 
  time.taken <- Sys.time() - start.time
```

The `time.taken` holds the time from the beginning of the process to its end. I would like to know how much time each addition in this case (as.numeric (i+j)) took. It means I would like to have two dimension array `time.taken[i,j]`. So that `time.taken[1,1]` would include the time for the first iteration till the last `time.taken[N,N]`. Is it possible to be done?

Comment: Have you had a look at the .multicombine option in combination with [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18993564/3250126)

Comment: Thanks @loki, can you please elaborate?

Comment: why not just `microbenchmark::microbenchmark(sum= as.numeric(i+j))`? IE- Why can't you use the timing of the serialized version?

Comment: Alex, this is only example. I would like to compare the parallel processing time to serialize processing time. The real code is much more complex.